# Secure WCF Service so that only my "clients" can call it

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, security

I'm about to write a WCF Service to run on IIS. The service will be called by a variety clients, including Android, iOS, Windows Phone, and Black Berry as well as possibly a Windows/Mac Desktop Client.

I understand that the client should always be treated as hostile. My design already incorporates several checks in the data to make sure that fake clients don't abuse it; however, I'm wondering what other techniques one can use to ensure that a service is only called by authorized clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could require transport-layer security (SSL) and distribute the appropriate keys out-of-band - I believe that's how it's usually done.

**EDIT**

How this is implemented server-side can vary based on the binding you're using.  To configure this for the vanilla wsHttpBinding, follow the instructions [here](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms).

The RESTful webHttpBinding also supports certificate authentication, but only with HTTPS - not just HTTP.

Comment: Any info on doing that? I've used HTTPS endpoints, but never had to distribute keys or anything...